# Axis and legend problems using hist3D in r

Tags: r, plot, legend, margins, par

**PROGRESS UPDATES AT BOTTOM.**

I am trying to get a nice looking 3D bivariate histogram using the `hist3D` function of the `plot3D` library. I've got the plot and colours working fine, but can't figure out how to manipulate the margins and axis labels properly, and the legend is also effected.

Currently I am getting rid of the original axis labels and adding a `text3D` (also from the `plot3D` library) to replace them, but I can't figure out how to give enough space for the x and y labels. I've worked around this for now putting the x labels in the plot, but ideally I'd like them under. I haven't figured out any such temporary work around for the y axis though. I'm guessing that it's something fixed with `par()` but I can't figure it out.

Simply, this is what I would like help achieving:

1. to move the legend further right out of the plot area
2. increasing the space between x-axis and title to fit labels
3. removing tick marks from x- and y-axis's.

Any help would be really appreciated. If you think you can get what I'm looking for using different packages, that would be just as good. I think the authors of the plot I am trying to replicate used Matplotlib, but I need this in R.

Below is where I'm at right now, sample data, and code.

Thanks!

[image]

```
library(plot3D)
library(viridis)

mydata <- matrix(sample(1:6,18,replace=TRUE), nrow=6)
rownames(mydata) <- c("biological regulation","biological_process",
                         "cellular aromatic compound metabolic process",
                         "cellular metabolic process",
                         "cellular nitrogen compound metabolic process",
                         "cellular process"    )
colnames(mydata) <- c("Group1","Group2","Group3")
mydata

m <- matrix(rep(seq(1:ncol(mydata)),each=nrow(mydata)), 
            nrow = nrow(mydata))

hist3D(z =mydata, scale = FALSE, expand = 0.1, bty = "g", 
       theta = 5, phi = 5, d = 2, r=20,
       border = "black", shade = 0.2, ltheta = 80, space = 0.8, 
       ticktype = "detailed", zmin=0, zlim=c(0,max(mydata)), 
       col= viridis(ncol(mydata)), colvar = m, colkey = F, 
       xlab = "GO Term", ylab = "", zlab = "Frequency", cex.axis = 1e-9)
#xlabs
text3D(x = seq(0,1,0.2), y = rep(-0.5, 6), z = rep(max(mydata)/2, 6),
       labels = rownames(mydata),
       add = TRUE, adj = 0.5,
       srt = 90, cex = 0.5)
#ylabs
text3D(x = rep(1.4, 3),   y = seq(-.2,0.8,0.5), z = rep(0, 3),
       labels  = colnames(mydata),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1)
#zlabs
text3D(x = rep(-0.18, 7),   y = rep(0,7), z = seq(-0.1, 5.9,1),
       labels  = seq(0,max(mydata)),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1)

legend("topright",
       legend = as.factor(colnames(mydata)), # category labels
       col = viridis(ncol(mydata)),  # color key
       fill = viridis(ncol(mydata)))
```

**PROGRESS UPDATE**

I have sorted the text clipping using `par(xpd)` and the sizes using `par(mar)`, and I got the legend out using `inset`. Still can't find how to remove the ticks. I think it's something to do with `persp()`.

[image]

```
library(plot3D)
library(viridis)

mydata <- matrix(sample(1:6,18,replace=TRUE), nrow=6)
rownames(mydata) <- gsub("( \\S+) ", "\\1\n", 
                         c("biological regulation","biological process",
                         "cellular aromatic compound metabolic process",
                         "cellular metabolic process",
                         "cellular nitrogen compound metabolic process",
                         "cellular process"))
colnames(mydata) <- c("Group1","Group2","Group3")
mydata

m <- matrix(rep(seq(1:ncol(mydata)),each=nrow(mydata)), 
            nrow = nrow(mydata))

opar <- par(xpd=TRUE, mar=c(7,4,4,4))
hist3D(z =mydata, scale = FALSE, expand = 0.1, bty = "g", 
       theta = 5, phi = 5, d = 2, r=20,
       border = "black", shade = 0.2, ltheta = 80, space = 0.8, 
       ticktype = "detailed", zmin=0, zlim=c(0,max(mydata)), 
       col= viridis(ncol(mydata)), colvar = m, colkey = F, 
       xlab = "", ylab = "", zlab = "Frequency", cex.axis = 1e-9)
#xlabs
text3D(x = seq(0,1,0.2), y = rep(-0.5, 6), z = rep(-0.5, 6),
       labels = rownames(mydata),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1,
       srt = 90, cex = 0.75)
#ylabs
text3D(x = rep(1.4, 3),   y = seq(-.2,0.8,0.5), z = rep(0, 3),
       labels  = colnames(mydata),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1)
#zlabs
text3D(x = rep(-0.18, 7),   y = rep(0,7), z = seq(-0.1, 5.9,1),
       labels  = seq(0,max(mydata)),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1)

legend("topright",
       legend = as.factor(colnames(mydata)), # category labels
       col = viridis(ncol(mydata)),  # color key
       fill = viridis(ncol(mydata)), 
       inset=c(-0.1,0))
par(opar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that I can turn all the axes off using `axes = F` in the `hist3d` call, and that's good enough for me. I then can add in axes titles at will.

```
library(plot3D)
library(viridis)

mydata <- matrix(sample(1:6,18,replace=TRUE), nrow=6)
rownames(mydata) <- gsub("( \\S+) ", "\\1\n", 
                         c("biological regulation","biological process",
                           "cellular aromatic compound metabolic process",
                           "cellular metabolic process",
                           "cellular nitrogen compound metabolic process",
                           "cellular process"))
colnames(mydata) <- c("Group1","Group2","Group3")
mydata

m <- matrix(rep(seq(1:ncol(mydata)),each=nrow(mydata)), 
            nrow = nrow(mydata))

opar <- par(xpd=TRUE, mar=c(7,4,4,4))
hist3D(z =mydata, scale = FALSE, expand = 0.1, bty = "g", 
       theta = 5, phi = 5, d = 2, r=20,
       border = "black", shade = 0.2, ltheta = 80, space = 0.8, 
       ticktype = "detailed", zmin=0, zlim=c(0,max(mydata)), 
       col= viridis(ncol(mydata)), colvar = m, colkey = F, axes = F)
#xlabs
text3D(x = seq(0,1,0.2), y = rep(-0.5, 6), z = rep(-0.5, 6),
       labels = rownames(mydata),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1,
       srt = 90, cex = 0.75)
#zlabs
text3D(x = rep(-0.18, 7),   y = rep(0,7), z = seq(-0.1, 5.9,1),
       labels  = seq(0,max(mydata)),
       add = TRUE, adj = 1)
#z title
text3D(x = -0.6,   y = max(mydata)/2 , z = 0,
       labels  = "Frequency",
       add = TRUE, adj = 0.5, srt = 90)

legend("topright",
       legend = as.factor(colnames(mydata)), # category labels
       col = viridis(ncol(mydata)),  # color key
       fill = viridis(ncol(mydata)), 
       inset=c(-0.1,0))
par(opar)
```

[image]